# Determining the path of a particle in a velocity selector

Tags: electromagnetism, kinematics, magnetic-fields

I am wondering how you can determine the path of a particle in a velocity selector provided its velocity doesn't equal $ \frac{E}{B} $. I understand that the equation is derived from this force equation,

$\sum \vec{F} = qvB- qE = ma$,

where $a = 0$, but I cannot show analytically how its path would differ should its velocity be greater than or less than $ \frac{E}{B} $. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Like always, add up the forces to determine the motion. Keep track of the directions too; e.g. $vB$ is a cross product.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is how to figure out a path given a particular $v$, yes? In this case, it's a kinematic problem: determining path from acceleration and velocity. I'd start your search for "physics basic kinematics."

Comment: What does "analytically" mean? If the velocity is too high, the particle will curve up, and if it's too low, the particle will curve down (depending on the orientation of the setup and the particle charge).

Comment: I guess what I meant was "quantitatively". Nonetheless I solved for acceleration, and discovered how the motion (up or down relative to the slit), is dependent on the particles initial velocity. Thanks for the help.